# What is the logic behind the terminology lyophilic and lyophobic colloids?

Tags: physical-chemistry, surface-chemistry, surfactants, colloids

Its given in my text book that-

> Colloidal dispersions of starch,rubber,proteins etc are lyophilic colloids whereas colloidal dispersions of metals,sulphides etc are lyophobic in nature.

But even the protein molecules have both hydrophilic as well as hydrophobic ends. And metals being ionised have strong affinity for polar dispersion medium. They why is it given that metals sols are lyphobic whereas sols generated from macromolecules are  lyophilic colloids.

Is it because we can create protein or other macromolecular sols just by simply shaking in dispersions medium and generation of metal sols require certain chemical and mechanical means.

What is the real definition for lyophilic colloids and lyophobic colloids?

Comment: The ease of preparation of such macromolecular sols over metal sols is virtue of being lyophilic. Lyophilic ('solvent loving') colloids are the colloidal systems in which the dispersed phase is strongly bonded to the dispersion medium,they are extensively hydrated due to the presence of polar groups. Unlike lyophobic ('solvent hating')colloids where the electrical charges of the solid particles of the dispersed phase and that of dispersion medium establish repulsion forces, which help to remain away from each other in the colloidal system. Thus destabilizing it and making it hard to prepare.

Comment: @SirArthur7, this might be a good answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yeah I think you're right. The thing is I just knew it superficially and that too was taught to me long before, so I wasn't totally sure and was looking for a 2nd opinion. I know the comment went too long, sure would post an answer soon.